# React router error about redirecting to the current route. Unsure how to properly structure routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I have a repo to reproduce this and see the error: https://github.com/rublev/parcel-static1/tree/master

The basic structure of my routes is as follows:

```
// app/app.js
const render = Component => {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <AppContainer>
            <Provider store={ store }>
                <ConnectedRouter history={ history }>
                    <Route component={ Component } />
                </ConnectedRouter>
            </Provider>
        </AppContainer>,
        document.getElementById('react-root')
    )
}

// app/containers/App/index.js
<div className='app'>
    <Switch location={ location }>
        <Route exact path='/' render={() => (
            loggedIn ? (
                <Redirect to='/organizations' push />
            ) : (
                <Redirect to='/onboarding' push />
            )
        )}/>
        <Route path='/organizations' component={ Organizations } />
        <Route path='/onboarding' component={ Onboarding } />
        <Route path='/settings' component={ Settings } />
    </Switch>
</div>

// app/flows/onboarding/Onboarding/index.js
<div>
    <Route exact path={`${match.url}`} component={ Start }/>
    <Route path={`${match.url}/signup`} component={ SignUp }/>
    <Route path={`${match.url}/name`} component={ Name }/>
    <Route path={`${match.url}/structure`} component={ Structure }/>
    <Route path={`${match.url}/pricing`} component={ Pricing }/>
    <Route path={`${match.url}/continue`} component={ Continue }/>
</div>

// app/flows/onboarding/Start/index.js
<div className='start'>
    Start Page
</div>
```

I'm not sure where the error could be coming from or how to do this different.

I have three main routes:

- /onboarding
- /organizations
- /settings

I'd like to redirect to either `/onboarding` or `/settings` depending on login state. Once at either of these main routes, there will be sub routes.

What is the proper way to set these routes up with a redirect without causing a redirect error?

error on launching `localhost:8080/`:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your render function, change

```
<Route component={ Component } />
```

to

```
<Component />
```

Also, you shouldn't need to pass `location` as a prop into the `Switch` in `App`.

Comment: That did not work. Which render function? Of the first app.js? I did that and I got a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined` error. Removing the location in the switch however did.

Comment: Yes, I'm referring to the `render` function that calls `ReactDOM.render`. Just to clarify, sounds like removing `location` from the `Switch` fixed it for you, though, right?

Comment: actually it didn't work, it broke my animations. Now instead of fading out the old page and fading in the new one. It duplicates both components and fades one in, fades the other out, looks extremely awkward.

Comment: Animation sounds like a separate issue. Routing should be working correctly now